# Problem with number/type of arguments passed to an overloaded c++ constructor wrapped with swig

Tags: python, swig

I am trying to wrap a c++ class (let's call it "Spam") written by someone else with swig to expose it to Python.
After solving several problems, I am able to import the module in python, but when I try to create an object of such class I obtain the following error:

```
 foo = Spam.Spam('abc',3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Spam.py", line 96, in __init__
    this = _Spam.new_Spam(*args)
NotImplementedError: Wrong number of arguments for overloaded function 'new_Spam'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    Spam(unsigned char *,unsigned long,bool,unsigned int,SSTree::io_action,char const *)
    Spam(unsigned char *,unsigned long,bool,unsigned int,SSTree::io_action)
    Spam(unsigned char *,unsigned long,bool,unsigned int)
    Spam(unsigned char *,unsigned long,bool)
    Spam(unsigned char *,unsigned long)
```

Googling around, I realized that the error is probably caused by the type of the arguments and not by the number (which is quite confusing), but I still cannot identify. I suspect the problem lies in passing a string as the first argument, but have no idea on how to fix it (keep in mind that I know almost no c/c++).

Answer (score 2):

SWIG treats strings as 'char*'.  Your use of 'unsigned char *' is most likely confusing it. You can either change the signature to 'char *' or provide a typemap:

```
%typemap(in) unsigned char * = char*
```

Comment: Yes, through trial and error I figured out that the problem was there. I was thinking of writing a subclass of the original problematic class with a constructor casting the parameter, since I hadn't figured out how to use typemaps. I'll try your solution and let you know...

Comment: No luck: I tried adding the typemap to my interface file, but I get a sintax error. I guess I should study a bit more typemaps.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
%typemap(in) (unsigned char *) = (char *);
```

Answer (score -2):

This can be solved by modifying the lines 100 to 110

```
self.source = uhd_receiver(options.args, symbol_rate,
                           options.samples_per_symbol,
                           options.rx_freq, 
                           options.rx_gain, options.spec, options.antenna,
                           options.verbose)

self.sink = uhd_transmitter(options.args, symbol_rate,
                            options.samples_per_symbol,
                            options.tx_freq, 
                            options.tx_gain, options.spec, options.antenna,
                            options.verbose)
```

to the following

```
self.source = uhd_receiver(options.args, symbol_rate,
                           options.samples_per_symbol, 
                           options.rx_freq, 
              ---------->  options.lo_offset,
                           options.rx_gain, options.spec, options.antenna,
              ---------->  options.clock_source,
                           options.verbose)

self.sink = uhd_transmitter(options.args, symbol_rate,
                            options.samples_per_symbol, 
                            options.tx_freq,
              ---------->   options.lo_offset, 
                            options.tx_gain, options.spec, options.antenna,
              ---------->   options.clock_source, 
                            options.verbose)
```

Best of luck

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add the reason to do so.